# Android register to remote server on first application uses

Tags: android

I am writing a android application where I want to register my application to remoter server when application is first launched on installation. Application will register to remoter server itself without taking any user input. How Can I track whether this is a first application launch after installation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By setting a shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.setBoolean("launched", true);
edit.commit();
```

You can check for it on each launch with:

```
boolean launched = prefs.getBoolean("launched", false);
```

Comment: Thanks synic for your quick response!!